# How to use data retrieved from a web API?

Tags: web-scraping, export-to-excel

I have a simple concept where I want to retrieve a table from a website and use it in that exact format. This can be for example imported into Excel.
This is the website that I want to get the table from:
http://www.dota2.com/leaderboards/#europe

This is the API that the website uses to get the data:
http://www.dota2.com/webapi/ILeaderboard/GetDivisionLeaderboard/v0001?division=europe

In all the ways I attempted to get the data from the website, it is poorly formatted into one line, and I was wondering what is the best way to format/use this data through code or other tools available. I have tried:

- Excel web importing
- Writing a simple VB program to read each line (but it reads it all as one line)
- Copy and pasting the table to Notepad to try format it by line(still one single line)

Any tips/suggestions regarding any form of website data retrieving is very much appreciated.

Comment: Paste the full JSON into this converter https://konklone.io/json/

Comment: Or do you want a small webapp which converts it for you ?

Comment: Thank you, the first link really works well. I did not know that the raw data that you get from APIs was called JSON. I think this will let me to research in new ways, thanks again!

Comment: Use Chrome or install a JSON previewer in your browser. Than you get nice data, instead of one poor line ;)

Comment: But what is your target ? A program ? A website ? For a website you could retrieve the URL via ajax. Then you have a nice objectlist -> walk through the list and render it on your website. Tadaaa

Comment: It's something more petty, just wanted to sort them by several rows for personal use, but this is also a good practise just for being able to retrieve data in a nice format. Your help is very appreciated!